# Adding entities to solr using solrj and schema.xml

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I would like to add entities to documents like you can do with the data-config.
At the moment I'm indexing every page of my documents as a single document.

Now :

```
<solrDoc>
<id>1</id>
<docname>test.pdf</docmname>
<pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
<pagecontent>blablabla</pagecontent>
</solrDoc>

<solrDoc>
<id>2</id>
<docname>test.pdf</docmname>
<pagenumber>2</pagenumber>
<pagecontent>blablabla</pagecontent>
</solrDoc>
```

As you can see the data related to the document is stored x pages times. I would like to get documents like this:

```
<doc>
<id>1</id>
<docname>test.pdf</docmname>
<pageEntries> //multivaluefield
<pageEntry><pagenumber>1</pagenumber><pagecontent>blablabla</pagecontent></pageEntry>
<pageEntry><pagenumber>2</pagenumber><pagecontent>blablabla</pagecontent></pageEntry>
</pageEntries>
</doc>
```

**I don't know how to make something like pageEntry. I saw that solr can import entities from databases but I'm wondering how I can do the same?** (or something similar)

I'm using solr 3.6.1. The page extraction is done by myself using pdfbox.

Java code:

```
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
solrDoc.setField("id", 1);
solrDoc.setField("filename", "test");
            for (int p : pages) {
                solrDoc.addField("page", p);
            }
            for (String pc : pagecont) {
                solrDoc.addField("pagecont", pc);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the extraction is performed by you, you can club all the pages and feed it as a single Solr document with the pagenumber & pagecontent being multivalued fields.

You can use the same id for all the pages (with the id not being a primary field in the schema definition) and use Grouping ([Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)) to group the results for the documents.

Comment: K but how can 2 multivaluefields relate to each other? I mean I got a multivaluefield pagenumber and a multivaluefield page. How can I say that pagenumber is related to that pagecontent?

Comment: By my experience for the multivalued fields are maintained by order and hence you pagenumber and pagecontent would always match as fed. You can surely recheck.

Comment: K I didn't know that multivalued fields kept their order. I hope I can build something around that. Can I still get the page where the query was found with this way of working?.

Comment: Nope .. With multivalued fields it would be tough to get back the page number of match. you may prefer using grouping which would give you the total matches the document that match (which is actually your page). There was also some work already for this (not sure if is converted to a JIRA), you may need to dig deeper to search on it.

Comment: I think the second option was kinda what I was doing at the moment I'm making each page a document with a primary unique id_page and another field with just the id. And I could group on that id field. Ithat I have loads of fields that aren't related to a single page. So I would store the same data alot.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplication Check Query time Solr Join @ http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/412000. This will help you to join it to a parent. However, am not sure if will be suffice some of your other requirements.